# create new tables from different column IDs (python)

Tags: python, try-catch

Hello I am trying to create new tables (with same attributes) querying from specific records in a column in a main table using python scripting.
ie. [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QlwE.png)

Column name: **OPID**
**records:**
12345
32502
31720
1169

I want each different OPID (4 of them) to have a new table created with same columns as the main table.

I want to run this using a **try and catch** process
Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: Please paste the table as text and not as an image

Comment: ok I have added the data as text. thanks